# Android restore from backstack give me blank fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have problem with backstack. Here is the list of my fragments:
A - Dashboard Fragment
B - NewOrders Fragment
C - Product Fragment

Backstack is working when I navigate A -> B (back pressed) -> A - this is OK

But in this situation A -> B -> C (back pressed) -> B (blank fragment) (back pressed) -> A (blank fragment)

Dashboard Fragment:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
public static final String TAG = DashboardFragment.class.getSimpleName();
ImageButton scan;
ImageButton paragon;
ImageButton cart;
ImageButton orders;

public DashboardFragment() { }

public static DashboardFragment newInstance(){
    return new DashboardFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment active: ************************************************************");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    scan = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    paragon = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.paragonButton);
    cart = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cartButton);
    orders = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newOrdersButton);
    scan.setOnClickListener(this);
    paragon.setOnClickListener(this);
    cart.setOnClickListener(this);
    orders.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.paragonButton:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, ReceiptFragment.newInstance());
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            break;
        case R.id.scanButton:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, ProductsFragment.newInstance());
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            break;
        case  R.id.cartButton:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, CartFragment.newInstance());
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            break;
        case R.id.newOrdersButton:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, NewOrdersFragment.newInstance());
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

NewOrdersFragment:

```
public class NewOrdersFragment extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener{
private static final String TAG = NewOrdersFragment.class.getSimpleName();
List<JsonNewOrder> newOrderList;
ExpandableListView listView;

public NewOrdersFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment active: ************************************************************");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_orders, container, false);
    newOrderList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    listView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    listView.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), newOrderList));
    return rootView;
}


public static Fragment newInstance() {
    return new NewOrdersFragment();
}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Long productId = ((JsonOrder)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).getBarcode();
    ProductFragment fragment = ProductFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(productId));
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(NetworkHelper.isConnected(getActivity())) new JSONTask().execute();
}

private class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    ....
}
}
```

ProductFragment:

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_EAN = "ean";
private static final String TAG = ProductFragment.class.getSimpleName();
ImageView thumbnail;
private String ean;

public static ProductFragment newInstance(String ean) {
    ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EAN, ean);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ProductFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        ean = getArguments().getString(ARG_EAN);
    }
}

private void setImage(Bitmap image){
    thumbnail.setImageBitmap(image);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment active: ************************************************************");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    thumbnail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView gender = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gender_text);
    TextView category = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.category_text);
    TextView name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    TextView size = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.size_text);
    TextView color = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.color_text);
    ImageView color_thumb = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.color_thumbnail);
    TextView price = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.price_text);
    String [] projection = Product.getProjection();
    String selection = Product.C_ID + "=?";
    String [] selectionArgs = {ean};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(Product.CONTENT_URI + "/" + ean), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_GENDER_NAME)))
            gender.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_GENDER_NAME)));
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_CATEGORY_NAME)))
            category.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_CATEGORY_NAME)));
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_PRODUCT_NAME)))
            name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_PRODUCT_NAME)));
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_PRICE)))
            price.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_PRICE)) + " PLN");
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_COLOR_NAME)))
            color.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_COLOR_NAME)));
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_COLOR_HEX)))
            color_thumb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_COLOR_HEX))));
        if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_SIZE_NAME)))
            size.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_SIZE_NAME)));

        String [] stockProjection = {Stock.T_NAME + "." + Stock.C_ID, Stock.T_NAME + "." + Stock.C_NAME, ProductsStocks.T_NAME + "." + ProductsStocks.C_AMOUNT};
        Cursor stockCursor= getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(ProductsStocks.CONTENT_URI + "/" + cursor.getString(0)), stockProjection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stock_list);
            String [] from = {Stock.C_NAME, ProductsStocks.C_AMOUNT};
            int[] to = {R.id.row_stock_name, R.id.row_stock_qty};
            listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_stock_item, stockCursor, from, to));
        }
        //stockCursor.close();
        if(NetworkHelper.isConnected(getActivity())) new DownloadImage().execute(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Product.C_THUMB_URI)));

    }else{
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.productContainer, new NoProductFragment()).commit();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I don't have answer but I just want to say I really feel you on this... I'm always having backstack problems with `onBackPressed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are already handling the `onBackPressed()` properly and using the popBackStack() method to jump back to the previous fragment.

A fragment should never replace itself. You will always run into problems. Instead, tell the activity that you want to be replaced by another fragment. Something like this:

```
interface AppEventListener{
    void onNewOrdersSelected();
    void onDashboardSelected();
}

class MainActivity extends Activity implements AppEventListener{
    ...
    void onNewOrdersSelected(){
        //replace fragment with NewOrders fragment
    }
    void onDashBoardSelected(){
        //replace fragment with Dashboard fragment
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();

        if(count==0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else{
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
    }

}

class DashBoardFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
    public void OnClick(View view){
        AppEventListener listener = (AppEventListener) getActivity();
        ...
        case(R.id.NewOrdersButton):
            listener.onNewOrdersSelected();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I'll try it at monday and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi I've tried your solution but problem still exists. I noticed that if I send app to background (after reveiving blank fragment) and bring it to foreground again then fragment appears.

Comment: Looks like it could be something with the lifecycle of the fragment. Which fragment is this happening with?

Comment: this is happening when I'm going from Neworders to Product and back

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the code in the activity itself. I'm guessing that when you switch the fragments, you don't keep any reference to the fragment that was removed and it's garbage collected. So when you pop the backstack to go to the previous fragment, the fragment is already null. When you go back to the NewOrder fragment, do you pop the backstack or do you replace the fragment again with a new NewOrder fragment? If you are not creating a new fragment again, you may need to keep a reference to the previous one (preferably in the activity).

Comment: Hi I think problem is resolved I added to onBackPressed() this manager.popBackStackImmediate(); and I'm using your method with interface.